# Sails mongodb missing connection handling

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

Very simple and stupid question I came up with today when was playing around with sails and mongo db (adapter of the waterline odm). I just shut down the mongo while my sails server still has been running and saw nothing, neither in logs of sails or in the browser. How I could handle such situation?

Answer (score 0):

If sails.js attempts a connection to the DB you will most certainly get a message in your console if the Mongo server is shut down, but if no request is made that requires a DB connection, then you will not see any error because no error as of yet exists.

It sounds like you might require a process that will monitor your DB and check to make sure it is still running? There are Sail.js options where you could create a CRON job to check the connection. Or you could use other application monitoring services like New Relic to monitor your DB.

Comment: When i just sarting sails and there is no mongo server, than I get message, you're right. But if sails server is already running and I try to make a request to the mongo server, which might for example be crashed, than I get nothing in logs. It's strange that sails not trows any exceptions about it.

Comment: Seems like mongoose has a such monitoring process.
Mongoose connection error: [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]